# Java multiple data Jdbc and R2dbc problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-jdbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I wrote a project and I used r2dbc and jdbc there. Now there is a problem with the database. How can I separate them? The information comes but gives an error

`Operator called default onErrorDropped`

**Application.yml**

```yaml
   spring:
     liquibase:
       enabled: true
       url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/liquebase
       user: postgres
       password: 12345
       change-log: classpath:db/liquibase/db.changelog-master-main.yml
     datasource:
       driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
       hikari:
       minimum-idle: 5
     r2dbc:
       url: r2dbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/liquebase
       username: postgres
       password: 12345
       pool:
         initial-size: 100
         max-size: 500
         max-idle-time: 30m
        validation-query: SELECT 1


  server:
    port: 8085
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use only one data source. But you can configure both and switch between them on the configuration `application.yml`. Something like this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev00
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev00
    liquibase:
      enabled: true
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/liquebase
      user: postgres
      password: 12345
      change-log: classpath:db/liquibase/db.changelog-master-main.yml
    datasource:
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      hikari:
      minimum-idle: 5
    server:
      port: 8085
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev01
    r2dbc:
      url: r2dbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/liquebase
      username: postgres
      password: 12345
      pool:
        initial-size: 100
        max-size: 500
        max-idle-time: 30m
        validation-query: SELECT 1
    server:
      port: 8085
```

Then you decide which one to use by configuring `spring.profiles.active: dev00` or `spring.profiles.active: dev01`. This [sample project](https://github.com/jahe/spring-boot-multiple-datasources) gives you a good source code.